# Как влияет амперсанд на вычисление?

Tags: golang

Хотел бы узнать как влияет амперсанд `&` на вычисление, допустим у меня есть две переменные `b, a` они все типа `int`, код?

```
var a = 0x3f
var b = 0x10
```

Я видел во многих исходных кодах используют вот такую конструкцию:

```
значение&значение2
```

В моем случае вот такое:

```
total := (a & b)
```

И в итоге я получу: `16`
Хочется узнать как это работает, буду очень благодарен за ответ :)

Comment: Я не знаю go, но вангую что это операция побитового «И»

Comment: Хочу причину закрытия вопроса «написано в каждом первом учебнике»

Answer (score 0):

Это операция [побитового «И»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8#%D0%98):

```golang
x := 0x03 // 0011
y := 0x05 // 0101
fmt.Printf("%04b", x&y)
// Output:
//   0001
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Dxc4aDC42mi.